# How to download a file using download manger and save it to the internal storage of the app (i.e. fileDir)

Tags: android, kotlin, android-download-manager

I tried the below way but when I fetched all the files in requireContext().filesDir. Download file was not present there.

```
setDestinationInExternalFilesDir(context, context.filesDir.absolutePath,
                  fileName)
```

I also tried using setDestinationUri() it created the below crash.
[image]

Comment: `I tried the below way but when I fetched all the files in requireContext().filesDir` You should have tried instead .externalFilesDir.

Comment: `context.filesDir.absolutePath` That does not make sense as when it works you would create all those subdirectories. So better use one folder name. Also post the logcat as text. Remove your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I did it then, first of all download manager doesn't allow to download files directly into the private storage of the app.

so I had to use okhttp to do the same thing and it worked fine.

```
/**
 * Method to download the file in to the private storage of app,
 * this method won't show any downloading notification neither any toast message on
 * download start and download complete.
 */
private fun downloadFileInInternalStorage(link: String, fileName: String) {
    val mFileName = fileName.replace(" ", "_")
        .replace(Pattern.compile("[.][.]+").toRegex(), ".")

    val request = Request.Builder()
        .url(link)
        .build()
    val client = OkHttpClient.Builder()
        .build()

    client.newCall(request).enqueue(object: Callback {
        override fun onResponse(call: Call, response: Response) {
            val fileData = response.body?.byteStream()
            if (fileData != null) {
                try {
                    context.openFileOutput(mFileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE).use { output ->
                        output.write(fileData.readBytes())
                    }
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }
            }
        }

        override fun onFailure(call: Call, e: IOException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    })
}
```