# How to save downloaded text files to internal storage for Android Lollipop and up (Android 11)?

Tags: android

I have this function to download a file and save it to public folder Documents:

```
private void df(String fn, URL url) {
File file=new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS)+"/" + fn);
if(file.exists())
    Toast.makeText(this, "File existed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
else {
    DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(Uri.parse(url + ""));
    request.setTitle(fn);
    request.setMimeType("application/text");
    request.allowScanningByMediaScanner();
    request.setAllowedOverMetered(true);
    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS, fn);
    DownloadManager dm = (DownloadManager) getSystemService(DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    dm.enqueue(request);

}
}
```

Is there a way to save or maybe move the downloaded file from Documents to internal storage? A set of codes or maybe a reference will greatly help me. Thank you.

Comment: What do you consider to be internal storage? Full path please.

Comment: Have a look at all `request.setDestination.......` functions.

Comment: @blackapps I mean Internal storage(GT): or "By default, files saved to the internal storage are private to your application and other applications cannot access them (nor can the user)"

Comment: That is not the information i asked for. Please mention full path or functions that give those paths. And did you have that look? Please react on all comments.

Comment: @blackapps I see. Alright like this path for example: /data/data/your.application.package.appname/someDirectory/

Comment: @blackapps So download the file directly to /data/data/your.application.package.appname/someDirectory/. If not possible then maybe transfer downloaded file from public Doucments to /data/data/your.application.package.appname/someDirectory/.

Comment: `And did you have that look? Please react on all comments. `

Comment: @blackapps I'm sorry what do you mean? I tried searching the internet on how to directly saved downloaded files to /data/data/your.application.package.appname/someDirectory/ or transfer files to the given path but I can't find any solutions yet.

Comment: @blackapps I look at request.setDestination....... and all I can see there are options to save the file to external public folders like documents, downloads,etc. No options to save it internally.

Comment: Why are you not mentioning .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() and .setDestinationUri() ? And why didnt you comment on them?

Comment: @blackapps that is because I don't know how to deal with them. My knowledge and experience is only limited to the code I posted. Yes I research on the subject but I can't find answers. Or maybe I don't know what to look for.

Comment: @blackapps a particular code or related (closely) to what I'm asking then, that will definitely help me and put me in the right track.

Comment: Dealing with setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() is the same as dealing with .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir() so i wonder why you are not trying that destination. That is the particular code you asked for. Or tell why it does not suit you.

Comment: @blackapps I see but will it save the file to an internal directory like /data/data/your.application.package.appname/someDirectory/? If yes, do you have a sample code or maybe a link for me to see and study? What I really want is 1. Save a file from a given URL to "internal storage". 2. If number 1 is not possible then at least transfer or move the downloaded file to  /data/data/your.application.package.appname/someDirectory/

Comment: We know what you want a long time. But we do not know why you did not try .setDestinationInExternalFilesDir() or gave arguments why it was unsuitable for you to use. You should have done that already at my second comment an hour ago.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73203346/how-to-download-a-file-using-download-manger-and-save-it-to-the-internal-storage